# Photoshop makes PNG low quality

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png

I just open a PNG image and save it again, but Photoshop make my image low quality. How can I solve this problem?

Original pic :

> [image: original image]

Saved pic:

> [image: saved image]

Comment: You must use 32 bit pngs if you want to have alpha levels in PS. Use some other compression tool

Answer (score 4):

You need to save you image as a 32 bit PNG. When saving your PNG from Photoshop, make sure you select '**PNG-24**' with transparency checked (the missing 8 bits from the 32 bit PNG you need).

PNG-8 (in Photoshop) only supports 1-bit transparency, which means every pixel is either transparent or not, which is why you get the jagged edges.

[image]

According to [this post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/284931/is-there-any-way-to-save-a-png-8-file-with-alpha-transparency-in-photoshop) you can save a PNG-8 with full alpha transparency if you use Export instead of Save for Web, but I don't have CC to check. In CS6 your stuck with using PNG-24 or the 1-bit transparency.

Comment: Well, to be honest its only photoshop that does this. PNG optimsation tools other than Photoshop can in fact do multilevel alpha on lower bit png files phltoshop is just a bit limited in this capacity.

Comment: Fair enough, the question was specifically about PS though :)

Comment: yes but it is  good to know that Photoshop has limitations. Sometimes stupid ones.

Comment: Updated my answer. Apparently you can save PNG-8 with full transparency in CC!

Comment: yes thets why they deprecated the save for web in CC

Comment: I guess I need to break my old habit of saving for web, I never knew PNG-8 had full transparency!  I'm so used to my old keyboard shortcut, but this is well worth learning a new one.  Great tip!

Answer (score 0):

Oh. Do not save your png as 8 bit image, save it as 32 bit image. That uses a alpha channel to make the transparency smooth.

The option you choose (just 8 bit) makes thoose jaggy borders.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an old version of Photoshop, like me, you can choose 'save for web' and choose PNG24. If you require a smaller file, you can use tinyPNG. This will give you the same result as the PS CC export. :-)

Comment: Why the downvote? What is wrong with this answer? TinyPNG subsets your colors, just like PNG8 does (but smarter and without the ugly edges). Just so you know.